# Distribution of 2 RVs whose marginals are sampled from a logistic-normal distribution

Tags: logistic, joint-distribution

## Motivation

I'm trying to understand and model interactions between binary variables. I'm not interested in the cases of independent variables where $p(\pmb{x})=p(x_1) p(x_2)$. As such, I'm trying to develop a toy model where I can control the degree to which $x_1$ and $x_2$ are correlated, as well as their marginals $p(x_1)$ and $p(x_2)$, and see how the joint distribution $p(\pmb{x})$ turns out.

## Setup

Let $\pmb{x}=[x_1, x_2]$ be a vector of Bernoulli variables; that is, $x_i\in\{0,1\}$ for $i=1,2$. Let the probabilities $\lambda_i=p(x_i)\in(0,1)$ be sampled from a bi-variable logistic-normal distribution, i.e.
$$
p(\pmb{\lambda};\pmb{\mu}, \pmb{\Sigma})
    =\prod_{i=1}^2 \big[ \lambda_i(1-\lambda_i) \big]^{-1}
        \big[ \mathrm{det}(2\pi \pmb{\Sigma}) \big]^{-\frac{1}{2}}
        \exp\left\{
            -\frac{1}{2} \big[ \mathcal{L}(\pmb{\lambda}) - \pmb{\mu} \big]^{\top}
            \pmb{\Sigma}^{-1} \big[ \mathcal{L}(\pmb{\lambda}) - \pmb{\mu} \big]
        \right\},
$$
where $\pmb{\lambda}=[\lambda_1, \lambda_2]$ and $\mathcal{L}(\cdot)$ is the element-wise logit function.

## Question

How do I model interaction between $x_1$ and $x_2$? Specifically, can I analytically find the joint distribution $p(\pmb{x})$? I know that $p(\pmb{x})\ne p(x_1)p(x_2)$ when the off-diagonal (covariance) of $\pmb{\Sigma}$ is non-zero, but I'm at a loss for any more concrete statements. I'm looking for a general solution to go from $p(\pmb{\lambda})$ to $p(\pmb{x})$.

**Sidenote**. This problem has been particular confusing to me because I'm working with probabilities of probabilities. I would also appreciate any tips on thinking about such problems.